# Basement Bedroom wiring help needed

Tags: electrical, wiring

To start it’s important to state my knowledge is minimal but I follow direction well and have watched all the YouTube electricians.  My goal is this, run a homerun from my panel to a roughed in 12x13 bedroom that will have 5 outlets, 4 led canless Halo lights on one switch, and on another switch two more lights in a closet. This bedroom will have a tv and Xbox used regularly, maybe a table lamp, but that’s about it.

My question is how I wire all this.  I’ve seen many different ways but looking for better direction and hopefully step by step direction.  The connection of all this confuses me as I’m not sure where to start the homerun or if I will need to use a 3 wire at all in any of this.

For material purpose , I’m not against using 12/2 or 14/2 in this room and I have plenty of room in my main panel.

Comment: "watched all the YouTube electricians" which probably means you've learned 10 correct things and 1000 incorrect things. _Please_ use common sense when learning from YouTube! Also, this is too broad a question for this forum. Please draw up what _you_ think is the "right" way to do it, then ask for pros/cons of that method - you'll get all sorts of input. At the moment, this is kind of "do my homework for me", and we're not really up for that. There are a wide variety of ways to do this _safely_, and none are really more "correct" than others, but some are definitely _incorrect_.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of options. My recommendation, if wire cost isn't that big a deal and you have room for two circuits in your panel (both of which seem to be the case based on the question as stated) is to run 2 20A circuits. Most likely you are in an area where AFCI is needed for *new* circuits. Most likely, because this will be finished space, GFCI is *not* needed for new circuits. You may already have some circuits in place that can be used (unusual even in an unfinished basement to have a 12' x 13' area with no receptacles at all).

The advantages of 2 separate circuits are:

- If you are working on one circuit (i.e., deliberately turned the breaker off) you still have the other one active to power tools or lights.
- If a breaker trips, you still have some power in the room.
- If you ever need more power, it is already available. For example, if a later owner (or a later use by yourself) wants to turn this into a home office, you have enough power for computers, laser printer, etc.

Some basic steps:

- 20A AFCI breaker for each circuit.
- 12/2 cable from each circuit to the bedroom. Note that if the cable is run through an open ceiling then you normally drill holes in the joists rather than staple to the bottom of the joists. Any place where the cable is outside of walls (or in a wall that is finished on the bedroom side but open on the other side) and below 8' normally needs to be protected from damage with conduit or wood or something.
- I would run one cable to 3 of the receptacle locations and one switch box for lights and the other cable to the other 2 receptacle locations and the other switch box for lights. Alternate the receptacle locations around the room between the two circuits - that will use a little extra cable but give maximum future flexibility.
- If you are running cable first to the boxes and then installing receptacles and switches, make sure to leave a loop of ~ 1' (or maybe even 1.5') in each box so you have plenty of slack to cut the cable and strip the ends, etc.
- In the switch boxes, each cable will attach to the switch (black wire) and the light fixture cable (white to white) and the switch will attach to the black wire of the light fixture cable. If you want to put in smart switches/motion detectors/timers/etc. then they will *also* attach to the white wires.
- I recommend metal boxes, but up to you.

There are plenty of other technical details - ask if you need help.

But **EGRESS IS VERY IMPORTANT**. Basement bedrooms often do not have a proper exit to the outside of the house. Typically a bedroom (as opposed to a home office or game room or whatever) requires either a door to the outside (without having to go upstairs to the rest of the house) or a window with certain minimum size and maximum height above the floor. If you don't have this worked into your plans, deal with that first before the details of electrical and picking paint colors. It is vital for fire safety.

Comment: This is one of the best answers ever.  It addresses safety in egress as well as wiring.

Comment: @RMDman Thank you! Because I am waiting for someone else to downvote me based on "they didn't ask about egress, they asked about electrical".

Comment: I can easily imagine shocking myself after assuming that a single 20A breaker toggles the room's receptacles off. I would be sure to put the breakers right beside each other in the panel box for idiot proofing.

Comment: @popham Nobody should ever assume a single breaker controls everything. It is generally safe in *modern* code-compliant setups to assume that everything on a single yoke (e.g., both halves of a duplex receptacle) is controlled by either a single breaker, a double breaker or a handle-tied breaker (MWBC installed to modern standards). But beyond that, **do not assume anything**. Classic example: Multiple light switches in one box that are on multiple circuits. Another example: Two duplex receptacles in one box (e.g., workshop) on separate circuits. And when they are in separate boxes (as I

Comment: recommend here) assuming that one breaker gets everything in the room - in multiple boxes - is a really, really, really bad idea.

Comment: @popham Another example: A kitchen is **required** to have *at least* 2 x 20A circuits. Unless that is done with a single 20A MWBC (double breaker or handle-tied), that is guaranteed to have at least 2 breakers for receptacles in the kitchen.

Comment: @manassehkatz, I'm familiar with the kitchen thing, but it's uniquely a kitchen thing, right? What's the max receptacles for a 20A circuit? 13, right? With the limited slots available to most people and the price of AFCI breakers, the expected pattern of all single bedroom receptacles on one circuit (with the lights in this instance tapped into an existing light circuit) seems reasonable and likely. I am an idiot, and I can't be stopped. (I'm all for a light at the panel box on its own circuit, but this answer seems to be taking that pattern to excess, in my idiot opinion. +1, though).

Comment: That explanation was perfect thank you! Now can you run 2 home runs to a double gang switch box?

Comment: Yes, you can. You just have to make sure the box is big enough. That's what is called "box fill". Which is relatively complicated (there are online calculators) but on a new install should be easy to handle.